# Strict warning: Only variables should be passed by reference (node.tpl)

Tags: nodes

Hello im getting this error message and its relating to this code in my node.tpl. Could anyone advise me on how i can clean it up a bit to suit. thanks?

```
 <?php print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'body', array (
 'label'=>'hidden', 
 'type' => 'text_summary_or_trimmed', 
 'settings'=>array('trim_length' => 150),
  )));  

 ?>
```

Comment: The code could be different, but the reason you are getting the error is the same, and so is how to fix the error: Use a local variable to store the value returned from `field_view_field()`.